# Responsive custom chart in angular

Tags: angular, graph, charts

in my angular web app, i need to dynamically create a structure chart like the one attached. I've checked on ngx-graph, google charts, go-js etc, but none fit into my exact need. 
Requirement is, the root node has multi parent and at multi direction. Edges to have comments as shown. Please suggest if there's a customizable out-of-the box solution for this using any of the graph generating tools. Or please suggest the best way to handle this.

For example i need to create a chart like this, for the given Json below

[Please click here to see the example chart](https://ibb.co/fU2JtU)

```
{
"class":"Class1A",
"type":"primary",
"Leaders":[
    {
        "name":"Leader1",
        "type":"HeadMistress",
        "comments": "Overall management"
    },
    {
        "name":"Leader2",
        "type":"Floor co-ordinator",
        "comments":"Floor level co-ordination"
    }
],
"Teachers":[
    {
        "name":"Tacher1",
        "type":"Maths",
        "comments":"Some comment"
    },
    {
        "name":"Tacher2",
        "type":"Science",
        "comments":"Some comment"
    },  
    {
        "name":"Tacher3",
        "type":"English",
        "comments":"Some comment"
    }
],
"Managers":[
    {
        "name":"Manager1",
        "type":"Academic Director",
        "comments"::"Some comment"
    },
    {
        "name":"Manager2",
        "type":"Chairman",
        "comments"::"Some comment"
    }   
]
```

}

Answer (score 0):

To those with similar requirement........
I was able to do this using GoJS
https://forum.nwoods.com/t/how-to-create-custom-chart-type-or-modify-existing-type-to-suit-the-need/10982?u=hsrashmi

Regards,
Rashmi